# How to get Jrebel, Sbt and JBoss AS 7 working?

Tags: jboss7.x, sbt, lift, jrebel, escalante

I'm using SBT 0.13.2-M3 for Lift 2.6-M2 development. I'm also using sbt-escalante 0.2.0 which allows me to start a different application server than Jetty. Now I tried to integrate JRebel 5.2.2 to avoid application restarts. When I run `escalante-run` I get a lot of JRebel exceptions and the JBoss application server starts but there's no class reloading.

There are so many exceptions that I just list two of them and hope someone has a clue how to fix it.

```
JRebel: Class 'org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.jboss7.cbp.DeploymentReflectionIndexCBP@sbt.PluginManagement$PluginClassLoader@411f8c70
2014-03-27 23:02:40 JRebel: ERROR org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.jboss7.JrDeploymentReflectionIndex
at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.ClassPool.get(JRebel:450)
at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.jboss7.cbp.DeploymentReflectionIndexCBP.process(DeploymentReflectionIndexCBP.java:22)
at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(JRebel:70)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xB.a(JRebel:257)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xB.a(JRebel:246)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xB.a(JRebel:224)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(JRebel:128)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xl.transform(JRebel:45)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)


JRebel: Class 'org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.jboss7.as.cbp.web.WebComponentInstantiator$1CBP@sbt.PluginManagement$PluginClassLoader@411f8c70
2014-03-27 23:02:48 JRebel: ERROR org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.jboss7.as.contracts.JrServletReinjector
at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.ClassPool.get(JRebel:450)
at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.jboss7.as.cbp.web.WebComponentInstantiator$1CBP.process(WebComponentInstantiator$1CBP.java:31)
at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(JRebel:70)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xB.a(JRebel:257)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xB.a(JRebel:246)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xB.a(JRebel:224)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(JRebel:128)
at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xl.transform(JRebel:45)
```

Comment: I suggest you report this to JRebel forums: http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/ Please tell what is the *exact* version of JBoss that you're using.

Comment: I'm using JBoss AS 7.x.incremental.667 and I posted my question at the JRebel forum. The thread can be found [here](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/jrebel-jboss-as-7-x-sbt-exceptions-and-no-class-reloading/)

Comment: When you find a solution, please post it here, too. Thanks!

Comment: it looks like a newer version of JBoss that haven't been tested with JRebel yet. And it looks like some internals of the application server changed. So the fix is required on JRebel side.

Comment: @AntonArhipov Thanks, good to know. I'll wait for a fix then. Anything in the pipeline concerning this new JBoss version? I guess the JRebel 5.x nightly build will be my friend then.

Comment: It should be fixed shortly. You'll get the answer to the forum post once the fix is available: http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/jrebel-jboss-as-7-x-sbt-exceptions-and-no-class-reloading/